# How might one prove the following inequality?

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $r$ be a natural number.  I wish to prove that $x + \dfrac{x^2}{2} + \dfrac{x^3}{3} + \cdots + \dfrac{x^r}{r} \leq x^{r+1} + \log(r+1)$ for all $x>0$. Some friends and I have tried using various calculus techniques but none of them seem to work. A solution or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Since $r$ is a natural number this problem lends itself to a proof by induction

Comment: Yes, we tried this but the inductive step is not obvious (at least not to us). Do you have a solution in mind or were you simply suggesting a general technique?

Comment: Just to be sure: $\log$ is $\log_{10}$ or $\log_e=\ln$?

Comment: By $\log$, I mean the natural logarithm $\log_e$.

Comment: Taking the derivative of the difference to find extremal points reduces the problem to showing that the inequality holds for positive x satisfying $\frac{1-x^r}{r+1}=x-x^{r+1}$.

Comment: I can do it for $ x \ge 1$ but I'm having trouble with $ x<1.$

Comment: For $0<x<1$, this was the best I could do

$$\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i} = \sum_{i = 0}^\infty x^i = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

So $$\sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i} = \int \frac{1}{1-x} dx = - \ln{(1-x)} + C = \ln\frac{1}{1-x}$$ where $C=0$ (evaluate at $x = 1/2$).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^{r+1}+\log(r+1)-\sum_{i=1}^r{x^i/i}$. We need to show that $\min_{x>0}f(x)>0$.

Differentiate and set to $0$: $$f'(x)=(r+1)x^r-\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}{x^i}=0$$ Clearly $f'(t)>0$ for $t\geq 1$, so solution(s) for $f'(x)=0$ lies in $(0,1)$ (at least one exists since $f'(0)<0$ and $f'$is continuous). Use $x^r=\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}{x^i}/(r+1)$, $x<1$ and telescoping product for $\log$:

$$f(x)=x^{r+1}+\log(r+1)-\sum_{i=1}^r{x^i/i}=x\cdot(\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}{x^i}/(r+1))+\log(r+1)-\sum_{i=1}^r{x^i/i}=\sum_{i=1}^{r}x^i(1/(r+1)-1/i)+\log(\prod_{i=1}^r\frac{1+i}{i})>\sum_{i=1}^{r}(1/(r+1)-1/i)+\sum_{i=1}^r\log(1+1/i)=\frac{r}{r+1}-\sum_{i=1}^r\big(1/i-\log(1+1/i)\big)>\frac{r}{r+1}-\gamma>0$$ for $r\geq 2$ (where $\gamma\approx0.577$ is Euler–Mascheroni constant). Separately check the case $r=1$ to get $f(x)\geq \log(2)-1/4>0$.

Comment: How did you get $x^r=\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}{x^i}/(r+1)$ ?

Comment: Rearranging $f'(x)=0$

Comment: By noting that $x<1$ and $1/(1+r)-1/i<0$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply -- it's a very nice answer!